# Do I have to CompareTo implementation?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, abstract, compareto

I am trying to search in a list but I sort as array so that I convert my linked list to array list but when I compile it without this part below. Command prompt gives "Person is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Person) in Comparable".

How can I fix this?

```
public int compareTo(Person other){
    if (!this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name))
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);

        return this.name + " "+other.name;
}
```

**Search list and sort methods:**

```
public void searchList(String search)
{
    if(phoneList.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("There is no record phone book.");
    }

    Node<Person> tempNode = phoneList.head;
    SLinkedList<Person> tempList = new SLinkedList();
    for(int i=1; i<=phoneList.size; i++) 
    {
        if (tempNode.getElement().getName().contains(search) || tempNode.getElement().getSurname().contains(search) || tempNode.getElement().getAddress().contains(search) || tempNode.getElement().getCell().contains(search) || tempNode.getElement().getHome().contains(search) || tempNode.getElement().getWork().contains(search))
        {
            tempList.addLast(tempNode.getElement());

            personArray = new Person[tempList.size()];
            Iterator<Person> it = tempList.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
            int x = 0;
            personArray[x] = it.next();
            x++;
            }

            bubbleSort(personArray );
            for(int x = 0; x < tempList.size(); x++) 
            System.out.println((x+1) + ""+ personArray[x]);

        }

        tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
    }
}

public <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> void bubbleSort(AnyType[] a) {
    int outer, inner;
    for (outer = a.length - 1; outer > 0; outer--) { // counting down
        for (inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++) { // bubbling up
            if (a[inner].compareTo(a[inner + 1]) > 0) { // if out of order...
                //then swap
                swapReferences(a,inner,inner+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

    public <AnyType> void swapReferences( AnyType [ ] a, int index1, int index2 )
{
    AnyType tmp = a[ index1 ];
    a[ index1 ] = a[ index2 ];
    a[ index2 ] = tmp;
}
```

**Person Class:**

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    public  String address;
    public  String cell;
    public  String home;
    public  String work;


    public Person(String name, String surname, String address, String cell, String home, String work)
    {
        this.name    = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
        this.cell    = cell;
        this.home    = home;
        this.work    = work;
    }

    // Accessor methods:
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getSurname(){
        return surname;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
    public String getCell(){
        return cell;
    }
    public String getHome(){
        return home;
    }
    public String getWork(){
        return work;
    }

    // Modifier methods:
    public  void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname){
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public void setAddress (String address){
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setCell (String cell){
        this.cell = cell;
    }
    public void setHome (String home){
        this.home = home;
    }
    public void setWork (String work){
        this.work = work;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + surname + " " + address + " " + cell + " " + home + " " + work;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person other){
        if (!this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name))
            return this.name.compareTo(other.name);

        return this.name + " "+other.name;
    }

}
```

Comment: `compareTo` should return an `int` not a string.

Comment: okey but how can I override the compareTo method, I search it but couldn't find the proper answer.

Comment: @rumay http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_compareto.htm

Comment: when you implement compareTo for a class, you should also override equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing *compareTo* method has a problem, but removing it violates the `implements Comparable` contract, since you *must* provide a compareTo method.

```
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    if (!this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name))
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);

    // next line returns a String, but the method needs to return an int
    return this.name + " " + other.name;
}
```

You can instead rely more directly on the standard String compareTo:

```
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    if ( this.name.equalsIgnoreCase( other.name ) ) { return 0 };

    return this.name.compareTo( other.name );
}
```

If you didn't have the *ignore case* constraint you've coded for, this would simply be

```
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    return this.name.compareTo( other.name );
}
```

---

As an aside, there is no reason to make address, cell, home, and work *public* — and that's generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement an interface you need to implement all the methods in that interface. You either remove `implements Comparable` part or add `public int compareTo` method to your class.

The rule of compareTo method is that :
- if this Person is greater than other , return 1
- if this Person is smaller than other , return -1
- if they are equal, return 0

Comment: `public int compareTo(Person other)` is in the Person class. It's the returned value that's bad.

Comment: But he says he got an error when he removes that method from the class.

Comment: I try to add compareTo method and I search everywhere but couldn't find the proper answer.

Comment: Yes. That and @Radiodef's comment on the question covers what's wrong. _With_ the method there is a compile error due to returning a String when an int is declared, _Without_ the method you get the error for not implementing it.

Comment: Thank you! But I try it and it gives "bad operand types error".